# One of several values as a type in Mongoose (union type)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make an API for sign-up, where user needs to enter their gender: "male" or "female". I tried this:

```
{
  gender: {
    type: "male" | "female"
    required: true
  }
}
```

But this does not work. I searched for solutions but I have not found a solution. Is there a way  to define type like this or the value should be checked on the server?

Comment: `"male" | "female"` just evaluates to `0`. It seems like you want an _enum_.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enum` in mongoose. Something like this:

```
gender: {
   type: String,
   enum : ["male","female"],
   required: true
},
```

Please keep in mind that the `type` here would be `String` and the value would be "male" or "female", it won't behave like other `enum`s, for example in TypeScript, etc.